# Not able to find ChangeTracker in entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to track the changes in entity frame work in wpf.But I am not able find out the defintion ChangeTracker and here it shows error.Below is my code I have written in my Cancel button in data entry form in wpf mvvm enity:
My command  delegate for Cancel:

```
_commands.AddCommand("Cancel", x => Cancel(), x => CanSave());
```

and my CancelSave method :

```
        bool CanSave()
         { return ctx2.ChangeTracker.HasChanges(); 
        }
```

Bu the ChangeTracker show errro saying entities does not contain a definition for change tracker.I am using visual studio 2010

This is instance of entity:
 TESTSEntities ctx2 = new TESTSEntities();

I am able save the changes in to data base throuhg :

```
       public void Save()
      {

          ctx2.SaveChanges();

          }
```

This is system generated class while creating entity from exisisting database table:

```
  public partial class TESTSEntities :          global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext
      {
         /// <summary>
```

Comment: Are you sure ctx2 is DbContext instance and not some other?

Comment: yes it is my context instance: class Listviewbindwithtextbox_VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        TESTSEntities ctx2 = new TESTSEntities();

Comment: What is base class of TESTSEntities?

Comment: I have successfully added record using this method: public void Add1()
        {
            addstatus = true;
            newprospect = new Prospect();
            newprospect.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
            ctx2.AddToProspects(newprospect);
            prospect = newprospect;
            Prospects.Add(newprospect);
            SelectedPerson = newprospect;
            ManageControls(false);
            label = "Adding...";
        }

Comment: Base class is edmx data model cs:

Comment: public partial class TESTSEntities : global::System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext

Comment: This save method will save records in to db: public void Save()
       {
           addstatus = false;
           ctx2.SaveChanges();
          // FillProspects();
           ManageControls(true); label = ""; 
       }

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext(v=vs.110).aspx
ObjectContext do not have ChangeTracker property, DbContext has it

Comment: However, you can use ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries method to get list of entities with givent entity state

Comment: Which EF version are you in? Only v6 has this `ChangeTracker.HasChanges()` method. There is a way to get access to it.

Answer (score 0):

OjectContext do not have ChangeTracker property, DbContext has it.

To get list of changes from Object context, Use ObjectStateManager for the ObjectContext instance, i.e.

ctx2.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added/Deleted/Modified)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstatemanager.getobjectstateentries(v=vs.110).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entitystate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am not able to find DbContext  in my entity

Comment: That is why I asked you to use your ObjectContext, which is ctx2 in code given by you